# Simple For Loop C++ why

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am just wondering why I would do this in c++

```
for(int i=0, n=something.size(); i<n; ++i)
```

vs

```
for(int i=0; i<something.size(); ++i)
```

..

Comment: Did you misspell the second example?

Comment: What makes you think you should do the first block of code instead of the second?  Personally, I would choose the second block.

Comment: @user2079139: It's currently not valid C++. Read it again very carefully.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming syntactically correct versions of both samples, if the call to `something.size()` were expensive, the first sample would potentially be more efficient because it saves one call per loop iteration. Even so, you should measure whether it actually makes a difference.

Note that the two would have different semantics if the size of `something` were to change inside of the loop.

Comment: I guess if the size changes, you'd also have the original size, but that's kind of questionable.

Comment: Thanks that makes perfect sense

Comment: @chris I think if the size change, you should not use a `for`loop in the first place.

Comment: @MartinSchlott, Yes, "questionable" means I would be suspicious of code that does that and would look at it extra carefully.

Answer (score 2):

The loop condition is evaluated before *every* loop round, so if the operand of the comparison doesn't change (i.e. you don't mutate the sequence during its iteration), then you don't need to recompute the operand each time and instead hoist it out.

Whether that makes a difference depends on how much the compiler can see of the `size()` call. For instance, if it can prove that the result cannot change during the iteration, then it may already do the hoisting for you. If in doubt, compile both versions and compare the machine code.

Comment: For example, you can hold [these](http://goo.gl/2rUkE1) [two](http://goo.gl/r2L9hu) versions side by side and compare.

Comment: I cant see any difference in the examples? Can you explain

Comment: @user2079139: Precisely :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
for(int i=0; i<something.size(); ++i);
```

it will be correct.
You should check in some C++ handbook how for loop looks like.
Your second example is invalid C++ code

Comment: @user2079139 It is invalid. You just can't see it despite all the clues ;-)

Comment: Haha my bad I see it Juan :)

Answer (score 0):

The two examples are not the same.

```
for(int i=0, n=something.size(); i<n; ++i)
{
    // ....
}
```

evaluates something.size() only once.

```
for(int i=0; i<something.size(); ++i)  // Syntax corrected 
{
    // ....
}
```

evaluates something.size() in each loop.

So they could behave very differently if something.size() changed while doing the loop.

If you know something.size() will not change, you should go for the first solution for performance reason (i.e. only one call to something.size()).

If something.size() can change (e.g. in the body of the for-loop) the second option is the way to go.